# SSRS total in Row Grouping for Column Values not the Field Falue

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

We are using SSRS in which we have following Query Result

```
LOC PD       SM     PG  Product  BUDGET     Amount  Month   Date    
DL  PD1     Anil    RR  SC      125000      1000.30 April   2015-04-03  
DL  PD1     Anil    RR  SC      125000      2500.30 April   2015-04-03  
DL  PD1     Anil    RD  SC      130000      1580.01 April   2015-04-03  
DL  PD2     Anil    PCH SC      150000      3611.00 April   2015-04-03  
DL  PD2     Sanjay  AG  AH      225000      1566.67 May 2015-05-04  
DL  PD2     Sanjay  AG  IW      225000      3380.48 May 2015-05-04  
DL  PD2     Sanjay  MG  IW       75000      2237.62 May 2015-05-04  
DL  Dist    Sunil   UP  AH      300000      523.33  May 2015-05-04  
DL  Dist    Sunil   UP  AH      300000      1258.17 April   2015-04-06
```

While Implementing this in SSRS in following Herarchy we get following result

```
                             Apr'15 - Mar'16            September 2015                  
Loc  PD    SM    PG    Budget       Amount   MthBdt     SC  AH  IW  %   07-09-15 08-09-15
DL   PD1   Anil  RR      1,25,000   3,501    10416.67   0   0   0   0          0      0     
                 RD      1,30,000   1,580    10833.33   0   0   0   0          0      0
            Anil Total   3,80,000   5,081    31,667 0   0   0   0.00 %         0      0
       PD1 Total         3,80,000   5,081    31,667 0       0   0.00 %  0   0
     PD2  Sanjay AG      2,25,000   4,947    18,750                     
                 MG        75,000   2,238    6,250                      
            Sanjay Total 5,25,000   7,185    43,750 0       0   0.00 %  0   0
          Anil  PCH      1,50,000   3,611   12,500  0   0   0   0.00 %  0   0
            Anil Total   1,50,000   3,611   12,500  0   0   0   0.00 %  0   0
       PD2 Total         6,75,000  10,796   56,250  0   0   0   0.00 %  0   0
     dist Sunil          3,00,000    1802   25000   0   0   0   0.00 %  0   0
            Sunil Total  6,00,000   1,782   50000       0       0.00 %      
      Dist Total         6,00,000   1,782   50000       0       0.00 %
```

DL TOTAL              16,55,000.00   17,135  1,37,917    0   0   0   0.00 %  0   0

Raw total of Amount is correct but is not correct in terms of Budget as Budget in query is link with PG, so should not get calculated transactions wise it should calculate column wise

it should display 2,55,000 insted of 3,80,000 in Anil Total , we have tried (Sum(Field!Budgey.value)) its giving this result and if we put only (Field!Budgey.value) its giving only 1,25,000

please guide is there any way where we can calculate the total of this value ?

Comment: Have you considered grouping the results by Person and getting a the Sum result of that.  Plus - the results there could really do with some tidying up - they're nearly impossible to read!

Comment: Row grouping is done first on PG then on SM then on PD and then on LOC, all the values in Amount column is coming ok and totals are ok and all the values in Budget(used direct field value and not sum(field value) is also coming ok but total of Gudget at PG,SM,PD & LOC is not coming product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any solutions through SSRS, but following changes in Query is worked for me, what i added is count of the PG

```
PGCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PG)
```

and created new BUDGET by dividing Budget to Count, and the same field value set in SSRS has resolve the Totaling Issue without any error

Thank